# jquery Datatables server side processing with .net MVC

Tags: .net, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to get my datatables implementation to use server side processing since we have a lot of rows to return per table instance. I'm stuck on handling all the query string parameters passed during the ajax call. I've increased the allowed query string length but the format of the "objects" in the query string don't seem to cooperate like I was hoping.

My controller signature looks like the following:

```
public JsonResult GetResultDtData(int testCycleID, int draw, int start, int length, Search search, List<Order> order, List<Column> columns)
```

I've matched up each of the objects there to have the same fields as what is sent in the URL and was hoping they would map correctly

The columns class for example:

```
public class Column
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Searchable { get; set; }
    public bool Orderable { get; set; }
    public Search Search { get; set; }
}
```

For a column object from the URL like this:

```
columns[0][data]=ExternalID&columns[0][name]=&columns[0][searchable]=true&columns[0][orderable]=true&columns[0][search][value]=&columns[0][search][regex]=false
```

The URL from Fiddler:

```
http://localhost:49278/TestResult/GetTestResultList?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=IsDeleted&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=1&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=2&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=LastModifiedBy&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=TestCategory&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=ExternalSysID&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=TestName&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Bdata%5D=7&columns%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B8%5D%5Bdata%5D=8&columns%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B9%5D%5Bdata%5D=9&columns%5B9%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B10%5D%5Bdata%5D=10&columns%5B10%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B10%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B11%5D%5Bdata%5D=11&columns%5B11%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B11%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=4&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&order%5B1%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=5&order%5B1%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&testCycleID=13&_=1425339243643
```

decoded:

```
http://localhost:49278/TestResult/GetResultDtData?draw=1&columns[0][data]=IsDeleted&columns[0][name]=&columns[0][searchable]=true&columns[0][orderable]=true&columns[0][search][value]=&columns[0][search][regex]=false&columns[1][data]=1&columns[1][name]=&columns[1][searchable]=true&columns[1][orderable]=true&columns[1][search][value]=&columns[1][search][regex]=false&columns[2][data]=2&columns[2][name]=&columns[2][searchable]=true&columns[2][orderable]=true&columns[2][search][value]=&columns[2][search][regex]=false&columns[3][data]=LastModifiedBy&columns[3][name]=&columns[3][searchable]=true&columns[3][orderable]=true&columns[3][search][value]=&columns[3][search][regex]=false&columns[4][data]=TestCategory&columns[4][name]=&columns[4][searchable]=true&columns[4][orderable]=true&columns[4][search][value]=&columns[4][search][regex]=false&columns[5][data]=ExternalSysID&columns[5][name]=&columns[5][searchable]=true&columns[5][orderable]=true&columns[5][search][value]=&columns[5][search][regex]=false&columns[6][data]=TestName&columns[6][name]=&columns[6][searchable]=true&columns[6][orderable]=true&columns[6][search][value]=&columns[6][search][regex]=false&columns[7][data]=7&columns[7][name]=&columns[7][searchable]=true&columns[7][orderable]=true&columns[7][search][value]=&columns[7][search][regex]=false&columns[8][data]=8&columns[8][name]=&columns[8][searchable]=true&columns[8][orderable]=true&columns[8][search][value]=&columns[8][search][regex]=false&order[0][column]=4&order[0][dir]=asc&order[1][column]=5&order[1][dir]=asc&start=0&length=10&search[value]=&search[regex]=false&testCycleID=14&_=1425398403512
```

The documentation suggested that all modern scripts will be able to handle objects and lists in this format, but is this true for MVC? I have a list of the objects in my controller but the fields are all null or default values. The only examples I've found have been in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, just needed to use Dictionaries instead of the Classes that I created

```
public JsonResult GetResultDtData(
        int testCycleID, 
        int draw, 
        int start, 
        int length, 
        Dictionary<string, string> search, 
        List<Dictionary<string,string>> order, 
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> columns)
```

seems obvious now...